# Text command with alteration of printed output numbers in each iteration

Tags: matlab, text, iteration

I have the line of code as below:

```
text(56,0.76,'r=0.275, R^2=0.0758, p= 0.07','FontSize',13)
```

but the value of `r`, `R` and `P` are changing in every iteration. How can I write a text command that could change the numbers in each iteration?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
txtStr = sprintf('r=%0.3f, R^2=%0.4f, p=%0.2f', 0.275, 0.0758, 0.07);
text(56,0.76, txtStr,'FontSize',13);
```

For more info take a look at the documentation of [sprintf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation like this:

```
strings = [    
            'r=',     num2str(r),
            ', R^2=', num2str(R^2),
            ', p=',   num2str(p)
          ]
text(56, 0.76, strings, 'FontSize', 13)
```

if the variables `r`, `R` and `p` are define.

Note: if you want to do this on multiple lines you can use `{...}` instead of `[...]`.